# Joining multiple properties of an object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate-functions

I want to create a action link combining two properties of object viz, **Name and Id**.

This is how I am doing right now,

```
 var hasDetails = collection.Count > 0;
 if (hasDetails)
 {
   <a>(</a>
 }
 for (var i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
   <a href='/test/@collection[i].Id'>@collection[i].Name</a>
   @if (i > 0)
   {
     <a>,</a>
   }
 }
 if (hasDetails)
 {
   <a>)</a>
 }
```

Is there a convenient way to do this using LINQ ?

Comment: To clarify, you mean "join" as in "concatenate" or `String.Join` - and not a SQL JOIN, correct?

Comment: yes . I don't mean SQL JOIN

Comment: It seems you are creating html elements by using Razor, why do you want to use LINQ? What exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Try use the https://knockoutjs.com library,  it is very easy to implement it in legacy code.

Comment: @SelimYıldız I want to achieve the same in simplified way

Comment: I think this question is about how to write in simply way which belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code solves your problem

```
@{var hasDetails = @Model.collection.Count > 0; }

@if (hasDetails)
{
    <a>(</a>
}
@for (var i = @Model.collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    <a href='/test/@@Model.collection[i].Id'>@@Model.collection[i].Name</a>
    @if (i > 0)
    {
        <a>,</a>
    }
}
@if (hasDetails)
{
    <a>)</a>
}
```